# How to get the central coordinates of a numbered grid?

Tags: c#

I have these buttons created in unity- 27 by 27 which has 9 by 9 sub-grids Each button is 10 by 15 pixels. When the user clicks on one, I want the program to to get the coordinates of the center of each sub-grid(which has no grouping) which are numbered 1 to 9(1,2,3)(4,5,6)(7,8,9)  There must be a neater way than metacoding

```
private int _num;
private int devy;
private int devx;
private float _Xcood;
private float _Ycood;
if (_num==1 OR _num==2 OR _num==3)
{ devy =1;}
else if (_num==4 OR _num==5 OR _num==6)
{devy=0;}
else if (_num==7 OR _num==8 OR _num==9)
{devy=-1;}
if (_num==3 OR _num==6 OR _num==9)
{ devx =1;}
else if (_num==2 OR _num==5 OR _num==8)
{devx=0;}
else if (_num==1 OR _num==4 OR _num==7)
{devx=-1;}
_Xcood=devx*15+position.y;
_Ycood=dexv*10+position.x;
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Apart it's not indented and then, unreadable

Comment: It doesn't work even with corrections  syntax- puts the location all over the place.